# Add character to beginning and end of column

Tags: text-processing, columns

I have a file like this:

```
78@54@this@15@23
65@22@is@92@16
34@12@an@14@18
13@42@example@52@22
```

And I want to change it to this:

```
"78"@54@"this"@15@23
"65"@22@"is"@92@16
"34"@12@"an"@14@18
"13"@42@"example"@52@22
```

I've been struggling on this for a long time and I can't understand how to do it. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try awk:

```
echo "78@54@this@15@23
65@22@is@92@16
34@12@an@14@18
13@42@example@52@22" |
awk -F@ '{print "\""$1"\"@"$2"@\""$3"\"@"$4"@"$5}' 

"78"@54@"this"@15@23
"65"@22@"is"@92@16
"34"@12@"an"@14@18
"13"@42@"example"@52@22
```

Comment: Ahh, what a simple solution, thank you. Why didn't I think of that? :-)

Comment: Just by the way: You don't need a line-continuation backslash `'\'` after the pipe `|` ... Actually, you can have whitespace and/or a comment after the `|`. You can even have multiple lines of comments between the `|` and the command.

Answer (score 5):

A little more verbose, but I'd write this awk:

```
awk -F@ -v OFS=@ '
    function quote(x) {return sprintf("\"%s\"", x)}
    {print quote($1), $2, quote($3), $4}
'
```

Comment: Compared to the other solutions, yours reduces the availability of human error and is significantly more readable.

Answer (score 1):

I think an [awk solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34949/73) is probably better, but you can also use `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/(\d+)@(\d+)@(\w+)(.*)/"\1"@\2@"\3"\4/' /path/to/your/file
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a mix of the two previous awk answers

```
`awk -F@ -vOFS=@ -vq='"' '{print q$1q, $2, q$3q, $4}`
```

Answer (score 0):

In awk: add quotes around the first three fields, then print the line.

```
awk -F @ '{for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) $i = "\"" $i "\""; print}'
```

`-F @` sets the field separator to `@`. The loop adds quotes around the first three fields. The final `print` (short for `print $0`) prints the line with the modified fields; `$0` is rebuilt whenever individual fields (`$1`, `$2`, …) are changed.